# np.where gives ValueError with two conditions

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, matrix, scipy

I have an array `image` with BGR values, it has dimensions 11x11x3. I want to select all indices of a specific color using `numpy.where` but I get an error message. Why?

```
indices = np.where( (image[:,:,1] == 55) and (image[:,:,2] == 32))
```

Error:

"ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()"

Comment: Use `&` instead of `and`.

Comment: `and` is a scalar Python operator.  Expressions like `(image[:,:,1] == 55)` produce a boolean array (with more than one element).  Their use with `and` produces this `ambiguity` error.  `np.logical_and` (or operator `&`) works with arrays.